# Recursion: putting people into groups of 1 or 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

let $n \gt 1$ be an integer, and consider n people; $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ let $A_n$ be the number of ways these $n$ people can be divided into groups, such that each group have either one or two people

determine $A_1,A_2,A_3$
So I have

$A_1=1$ way

$A_2=2$ way

$A_3=4$ way

and from this I derive the formula $A_n = 2^{n-1}$ but this is not true for $n\ge 4$

so I have to prove that for each integer $n\ge 3$

$$A_n = A_{n-1} + (n-1) * A_{n-2}$$

So I proved this by Induction:

Where I assumed that $n \ge 2$ so $A_{n+1} = 2^n$

So I did the induction step.. and I was wrong

I was hoping anyone on here could help me by proving this with induction?

Thanks

Comment: Your formula $A_n=2^{n-1}$ is only true for $n=1$, not $2$ or $3$ as well.

Comment: Your guess that $A_n=2^{n-1}$ only works for the $n=1$ case, since $2^{2-1}=2\neq4$ and $2^{3-1}=4\neq 12$. So you're trying to prove a formula that isn't valid. I'd suggest using your recurrence relation to derive a longer list of numbers so you have a better chance of seeing a pattern.

Comment: To get a clearer understanding of what you intend, and how you are counting, it would be helpful to see examples of how you formed the groups.

Comment: Shouldn't $A_2=2$?  Either two groups of $1$ or one group of $2$?  And I think $A_3=4$ (three groups of $1$ or three different ways to have a group of $2$ and a group of $1$).

Comment: Do you want to prove this induction formula or you want to find a closed form $A_n$?

Comment: John, I want to prove this formula by induction and show it is true

Comment: @NeedHelp You can argue this formula is true $\forall n\geq 3$ directly. I have writen down the details in my answer.

Comment: @JohnZHANG I know it can be proven by direct proof. But I also need to find a formula for An as well and the proof below does not find any formulas

Answer (score 3):

$A_n = A_{n-1} + (n-1)A_{n-2}$ can be shown by direct argument.

Case 1 from $A_{n-1}$ to $A_n$, we add 1 person, let this person forms a group alone, then we have $A_n$ arrangement. In total $A_{n-1}$.

Case2 from $A_{n-1}$ to $A_n$, we add 1 person, but we let this person form a group with another person from previous $n-1$ persons, so we have $n-1$ choices, the other $n-2$ persons have $A_{n-2}$ arrangement. In total $(n-1)A_{n-2}$.

Comment: This argument doesn't take into account the fact that a group cannot have more than two people.

Comment: @rogerl Why? It considered this condition, that's why we only have two cases.

Comment: Yes, the wording confused me. Your rephrasing is clearer.

Comment: Good answer +1. But note that "1 people" or "$n-1$ people" sounds strange in English; prefer "person(s)" to "people"in such cases.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I modified my answer based on your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Such arrangements of $\{1, 2, \dotsc, n\}$ correspond in an obvious way to elements of $S_n$ that have order $2$; that is, involutions in $S_n$. Now [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590402/number-of-involution-in-symmetric-group) solves the problem; see also [OEIS A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085).

There is a link from the article above to a Wikipedia page on the Telephone Numbers that provides some further exposition as well and discusses the recurrence you give. There does not appear to be a closed form.