# Degrees of irreducible complex characters of alternating groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

What is sum of degrees of the irreducible complex characters of the alternating groups?

The background of this question is to calculate the diminsion of a maximal torus of the associated Lie algebra of the group algebra $\mathbb{C} A_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

The corresponding sum for the symmetric group is known by the Frobenius-Schur-Indicators that is to calculate the involutions plus 1 in the symmetric group. This value is also an upper bound for the sum related to the alternating group (see also [Number of involution in symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590402/number-of-involution-in-symmetric-group))

I would like to know the difference betweeen these two values.

In addition the character theory of the alternating groups are closely related to the symmetric group by using Clifford-Theory: some irreducible are still irreducible by restricting them to the alternative group the other ones decompose into two irreducible characters.

In the article http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/JACO/Volume5_2/lmm440901p5p3660.fulltext.pdf these two irreducible characters of $A_n$ are investigated based on theorems by Thrall.

Comment: This seems a reasonable question to me. The answer for $S_{n}$ is well-known (in principle)

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Given you're an active MO user, do you think this will fit there? I am doubting it.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : I think it would be OK there. It's a question of knowing which representations of $A_{n}$ are realizable over the real field ad which are not ( plus character information).

Comment: Hi Geoff, did you find the answer? KR Sven

Comment: I think we should close the question.